# How to check my server supports PHP 7 syntax?

Tags: php, php-7

I have developed my solution using PHP 7.0 syntax. I was wondering whether my server supports PHP 7 syntax or not. Before uploading my source code I wanted to try some code to check if it supports PHP 7.0 syntax.

As I know **PHP 7 introduces the ability to define the return type of methods and functions** so unlike using some software or installing any scripts I tried some code snippets below:

```
<?php  
function a() : bool  
{
   return 1;
}
var_dump(a());
```

The above code wasn't working. Did that mean the PHP 7.0 syntax is not working in my server? Is there any other good way to check it?

Comment: Can't you just check the output of `phpinfo()`?

Comment: `phpinfo()` typically gives enough info; as does your average web hosting panel.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the php version in your command line can be different from the one used by apache webserver. This can be importand if you upgrade an older system with par example php 5.6 to 7.1.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "wasn't working".... what does var_dump() show? Or do you  get a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run script like this one:

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

And see what version of PHP it will report.